# __in filter only returning one value, show query through intermediate table

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

Noob at coding and need help. I am trying to render the view `article` by filtering through the model `Spots`. I have an intermediate table `ArticleSpots` to link the 2 tables `Spots` and `Articles`. In the views `article` I want to show only the spots that are linked to that specific article. My problem is that `Spots.objects.filter(id__in=articleSpots)` only shows the first one value and not all of the spots that are linked. What am I doing wrong here?

**views.py**

```
def article(request, slug):
    articles = get_object_or_404(Articles, slug=slug)
    article_id = articles.id
    articleSpots = ArticleSpots.objects.filter(article__id=article_id)    
    spots = Spots.objects.filter(id__in=articleSpots)
    
    context = {"spots": spots, "articles": articles}
    template_name = "articletemplate.html"
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

**models.py**

```
class ArticleSpots(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey('Articles', models.DO_NOTHING)
    spot = models.ForeignKey('Spots', models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'article_spots'
        verbose_name_plural = 'ArticleSpots'
        
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.article) + ": " + str(self.spot)

class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    metatitle = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=155)
    summary = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    field_created = models.DateTimeField(db_column='_created', blank=True, null=True)  
    field_updated = models.DateTimeField(db_column='_updated', blank=True, null=True)  
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to="cover", blank=True, default='logo-00-06.png')

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'articles'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Articles'
        
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + ": " + str(self.title)

class Spots(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    metatitle = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=155)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Authors, models.DO_NOTHING)
    field_created = models.DateTimeField(db_column='_created', blank=True, null=True)  
    field_updated = models.DateTimeField(db_column='_updated', blank=True, null=True)  
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to="cover", blank=True, default='logo-00-06.png')
    summary = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    content1 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    content2 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'spots'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Spots'
        
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + ": " + str(self.title)
```

**html**

```
<!-- START MAIN -->
    <main class="page"></main>
    <p>
      {{ spots.title }} <br />
      {{ spots.content1 }} <br />
      {{ articles.title }}
    </p>
    {% for spots in spots %} {{ spots.title}} {% endfor %}
<!-- END MAIN -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently retrieving `Spots` that have the same primary key as the `ArticleSpots` object, but that does not make much sense: it is possible that this is the case, but even if that happens, the returned `Spots` does not per se is linked to a relevant `ArticleSpots` with the given article.

You can retrieve the relevant `Spots` with:

```
def article(request, slug):
    article = get_object_or_404(Articles, slug=slug)
    spots = Spots.objects.filter(articlespots__article=article)
    context = {'spots': spots, 'article': article}
    return render(request, 'articletemplate.html', context)
```

I would strongly advise to name you `Article` object `article` since it is a *single* `Article`, not a collection of `Article`s. `spots` on the other hand is a collection of spots.

It makes no sense to render `{{ spots.content1 }}` and `{{ spots.title }}`, since `spots` is a collection of `Spots` that can contain zero, one or more items.

The template thus should look like:

```
<p>
    {{ article.title }}
</p>
{% for spot in spots %} {{ spot.title}} {% endfor %}
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Articles` instead of <s>`Article`</s>.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked like a charm!
Can you tell me what are these articlespots__article=article called ? I'm trying to find resources to study them

Comment: Also is there a way to remove the duplicates from Spots?

Comment: @haashe: `spots = Spots.objects.filter(articlespots__article=article).distinct()`.

Comment: Hello Willem, would really appreciate your help if you can look at another question I have posted here? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69684367/django-orm-using-pivot-intermediate-tables