# Django ORM : Using pivot/intermediate tables

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, orm, django-queryset

I am trying to render the view `article` by filtering through the model `Spots` and `Images`. I have managed to render the spots associated with each article, but cannot seem to render the images for each spot.

I have an intermediate table `ArticleSpots` to link the 2 tables `Spots` and `Articles`.
I have another intermediate table `ImagesSpots` to link the tables `Spots` and `Images`.

All spots associated with the article is rendered, but how can I render the images for each spot?

**views.py**

```
def article(request, slug):
    article = get_object_or_404(Articles, slug=slug)
    spots = Spots.objects.filter(articlespots__article=article).distinct()
    images = Images.objects.filter(imagespots__spots=spots)
    
    context = {'spots': spots, 'article': article, 'images':images}
    return render(request, 'articletemplate.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    metatitle = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=155)
    summary = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    field_created = models.DateTimeField(db_column='_created', blank=True, null=True)  
    field_updated = models.DateTimeField(db_column='_updated', blank=True, null=True)  
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to="cover", blank=True, default='logo-00-06.png')

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'articles'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Articles'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + ": " + str(self.title)


class Spots(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    metatitle = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=155)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Authors, models.DO_NOTHING)
    field_created = models.DateTimeField(db_column='_created', blank=True, null=True)  
    field_updated = models.DateTimeField(db_column='_updated', blank=True, null=True)  
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to="cover", blank=True, default='logo-00-06.png')
    summary = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    content1 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    content2 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)


    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'spots'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Spots'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + ": " + str(self.title)


class ArticleSpots(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey('Articles', models.DO_NOTHING)
    spot = models.ForeignKey('Spots', models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'article_spots'
        verbose_name_plural = 'ArticleSpots'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.article) + ": " + str(self.spot)


class Images(models.Model):
    note = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images", blank=True, default='logo-00-06.png')

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'images'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Images'
        
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + ": " + str(self.note)


class ImageSpots(models.Model):
    images = models.ForeignKey('Images', models.DO_NOTHING)
    spots = models.ForeignKey('Spots', models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'image_spots'
        verbose_name_plural = 'ImageSpots'
        
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.spots) + ": " + str(self.images)
```

**html**
I want to render it to something like below, where I display each spot and within the spot display images for each spot. How would I code this part?

```
<main class="page"></main>
<p>{{ article.title }}</p>
{% for spots in spots %} {{ spots.title }} 
{{ spots.content1 }}
{% for images in images %}
    <img style="width: 200px; height: 200px" src="{{ images.image.url }}" />
    {% endfor %} 
{% endfor %}
```

I tried it a couple of times but keep getting the error "The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing."

Comment: hi, perhaps render an `<img src="...">` in the template?

Comment: Do you think this part is correct in the Views.py?
images = Images.objects.filter(imagespots__spots=spots)
And how would I loop through the images to show only the ones associated with that spot?

Comment: In the html, change images for loop. An individual sample should be named individual: image.